# can not get canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(x,x,x,x)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

can not get the imageData

#### the browser console "Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Comment: I guess you've drawn an image from an external source before calling `getImageData`. Have you?

Comment: If you are still having trouble, post your code. That will help others in identifying the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to prevent shenanigans, the browser keeps track of image data. When you put an image from a different domain on your canvas, the canvas becomes "tainted" and the browser won't let you look at its pixels anymore.

This is necessary to prevent a variety of XSS/CSRF attacks.

Comment: This also happens with SVG regardless of source to prevent visited link detection, but this may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

See Pointy's answer for an explanation. This can be an annoying problem when testing files from the local filesystem. On Google Chrome / Chromium there's a workaround: Call it with the following command line option:

```
chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files
```